# .NET MEF Load unreferenced .dll's

Tags: c#, dll, mef

I've made a 3 layer web application (**web api** -> **logic**-> **DAL**). A Shared project contains all the interfaces used for injection the dependencies between the layers. I load my layers as components with MEF (reflection) Thus, the web api project does not have any build time dependency to the other layers! This means that the DLL's (logic.dll + DAL.dll) will not be present in the web api's /bin folder - and thus the MEF will not find and load my dll's.

Everything works if i just add an (unused) reference between the projects in the solution - but it makes no sense for me having this dependency... The whole purpose of using MEF components was to decouple everything and communicate through interfaces. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DirectoryCatalog** for such a task. Here is an example:

```
 var dirPath = @"Z:\MyAssemblies";
 var registration = new RegistrationBuilder();
 registration.ForTypesMatching(t => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t))
      .Export<IFoo>();
 var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(dirPath,registration);
 var container = new CompositionContainer(dirCatalog);
```

As you can see it recieves as a parameter the full path to the directory where youre dlls are. It then scan it and does known MEF stuff..

This way you achieve to decouple everything as you said.

Comment: I see. But i am still confused. Do i have to create a folder (eg. `@"Z:\MyAssemblies"`) where i store my DLLs? Meaning that i have to manually put my wanted DLLs in there? I use a TFS build server. When i build my application to the IIS server - this folder would not exist there, would it?

Comment: You can create a folder in your project and add DLLs in there and use relative paths. That is what I have done

Comment: `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "CoolDirName");` for instance